# Git diff stat changes when piped

Tags: git, git-diff, diffstat

If I do:

```
git diff --stat master
```

I will have something like:

```
 .gitignore                                           |  11 +-
 BUGS                                                 |   1 +
 Makefile                                             | 907 +++++++++++++++++++------------------------------
 README.md                                            |  55 +--
```

If I pipe it to a pager such as `more` or `less`, it'll change:

```
 .gitignore                                         |  11 +-
 BUGS                                               |   1 +
 Makefile                                           | 907 ++++++++-------------
 README.md                                          |  55 +-
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subsequent command is assuming a standard terminal width of 80 columns.

Resize your virtual terminal to 80 columns, you'll see piping will **apparently** cease affecting the output.

According Git diff help:

> [...] Maximum width defaults to terminal width, or 80 columns if not connected to a terminal, and can be overridden [...]